# How to access a specific element in ng-repeat generated collection with angularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I was trying to generate a list of items using `ng-repeat`. however, now I've done this step easily but I got stuck with another issue. so I was trying to access and update a specific element in the collection but I really can't figure out how to do this. Does anyone know how to do this? or can point me to the right direction?

here's a fiddle sample: http://jsfiddle.net/VNLPY/ (haven't done much really)

```
<body ng-app>
<div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', age:25}, {name:'Mary', age:28}]">
I have {{friends.length}} friends. They are:
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
[{{$index + 1}}] {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

one more thing, lets say the data I have is getting pulled from a JSON file. Now how can I access each value of each row inside the collection and if I update a specific row in JSON object. does the interface gonna be in-sync with the updated JSON?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VNLPY/7/) has an example of incrementing the age of a specific friend via an expression in `ng-click` as well as `ng-click` calling a scope function in a simple controller.

```
    <a href="" ng-click="friend.age = friend.age + 1">Age + 1</a>
    <a href="" ng-click="decrementAge(friend)">Age - 1</a>
```

With a controller defined as:

```
function TestController ($scope) {
    $scope.decrementAge = function (friend) {
        friend.age = friend.age - 1;
    };
}
```

Angular will handle keeping the model and the view in sync.

Answer (score 1):

You need to structure your app properly first. [Angular Seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) is a good starting point.

Once you have a proper controller & view you can use the $scope to achieve what you're asking.

**NOT TESTED**

**Controller**:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('FriendsController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.doSomethingWithAFriend = function(friend) {
     // do something with your friend!
  }

  // $http is almost the same as jQuery.ajax except all the methods
  // return promises based on the $q (q.js) spec.
  $http.get('/api/friends').then(function(resp) {
    $scope.friends = resp.data;
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

**View**

```
<li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
  [{{$index + 1}}] {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old. 
  <a href="" ng-click="doSomethingWithAFriend(friend)">Do Something</a>
</li>
```

*Edit*: I should mention the proper place to do API calls (or any AJAX/data manipulation) is in [Services](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services).  I just put it in the controller as a simple example.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I got the idea :)